# Error importing TIGER census block gdb in GDAL

Tags: postgis, gdal, ogr2ogr, census, tiger

I have downloaded the 2015 Census Block GDB for the entire country from the census website here: https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-geodatabases.html.

I am facing a problem in that when I attempt to use ogr2ogr to import this data into postgresql, using the following command:

"ogr2ogr -overwrite -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=localhost user=username dbname=blocksnearwater password=password" "tlgdb_2015_a_us_block.gdb" "Block"",

I get the error "Error occurred in filegdbtable.cpp at line 717". After doing some research on this, line 717 of the filegdbtable.cpp is "returnErrorIf(nFieldDescLength > 10 * 1024 * 1024 nFieldDescLength < 10 );", so that must mean that the field descriptor for this table is incredibly huge.

Is there anyway to import this file into postgresql using ogr2ogr? If not, is there another good tool that could be used to import a GDB file of this size? I am using this tiger data specifically because it contains information on if the block has a body of water in its area and I need that data for an operation I am doing. I am new to PostGIS, so my apologies if there is a rather obvious answer.

Comment: Was there any resolution to this issue? I am facing something very similar.